# File-missing "No such file or directory" "c:/emacs-26.1-x86_64/bin/%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%/"

Tags: init-file, microsoft-windows, directory

I'm launching Emacs using `runemacs` on Windows 7, from the emacs directory (`C:\emacs-26.1-x86_64\bin`), using `runemacs --debug-init`.

I get the following error text:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-missing "Opening directory" "No such file or directory" "c:/emacs-26.1-x86_64/bin/%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%/")
  directory-files("~" nil "^\\.emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$")
  #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1000be22d>)()
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

The HOMEDRIVE is set to "P:".
The HOMEPATH is set to "\".

I don't understand why the HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH would be concatenated to the CWD.

Where is this coming from?

Here is my `.emacs` file:

```
(set-default 'truncate-lines t)
(load-file "C:/emacs-26.1-x86_64/share/emacs/26.1/lisp/cedet/cedet.el")
(setq-default cursor-type 'bar)
(set-cursor-color "#ff0000")
(global-ede-mode 1)
(semantic-mode 1)
;;(global-srecode-minor-mode 1)
(require 'doxymacs)
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(blink-cursor-mode nil)
 '(c-basic-offset 4)
 '(c-default-style
   (quote
    ((c-mode . "linux")
     (c++-mode . "linux")
     (java-mode . "java")
     (awk-mode . "awk")
     (other . "gnu"))))
 '(c-offsets-alist
   (quote
    ((topmost-intro . 0)
     (comment-intro . 0)
     (indent-tabs-mode nil)
     (c-toggle-auto-state -1)
     (c-toggle-auto-hungry-state 1)
     (substatement-open . 0)
     (case-label . 4)
     (block-open . 0)
     (member-init-intro . 2)
     (knr-argdecl-intro . -))))
 '(c-tab-always-indent nil)
 '(column-number-mode t)
 '(cursor-type (quote bar))
 '(display-line-numbers t)
 '(doxymacs-command-character "/*!")
 '(doxymacs-doxygen-dirs
   (quote
    (("c:/menuplan/src/ingredient/" "c:/menuplan/docs/doxygen_tags.txt" "file:///menuplan/docs/code/html/index.html"))))
 '(doxymacs-doxygen-style "C++")
 '(inhibit-startup-screen t)
 '(tab-width 4))

;; Show filename in title bar
(setq frame-title-format "%b - Emacs")

(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )

(defun my-doxymacs-font-lock-hook ()
  (if (or (eq major-mode 'c-mode) (eq major-mode 'c++-mode))
      (doxymacs-font-lock)))
(add-hook 'font-lock-mode-hook 'my-doxymacs-font-lock-hook)
```

How do I fix this?

*(Note: Emacs suggest I restart with the "--debug-init", after I tried to open a CPP file using Windows File Explorer.  I have the CPP extension associated with `runemacs`.)*

**Edit 1:**

```
Original error text, when running from a short cut to `runemacs`:  
Error (initialization): User tmatthews has no home directory
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘nil’:

File is missing: Opening directory, No such file or directory, c:/emacs-26.1-x86_64/bin/%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%/

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the ‘--debug-init’ option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

Comment: In Windows (outside of Emacs), define environment variable `HOME`.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider setting the HOME environment variable to "P:".  I also have HOMEDRIVE set and HOMEPATH set (to "U:" and "" respectively), however Emacs wants to use HOME so I have it set to "c:\users<name>" and then I have ..emacs.d there, with my initialization at ~/.emacs.d/init.el

Answer (score 0):

I added the Emacs bin directory, `c:/emacs-26.1-x86_64/bin` to my `PATH` environment variable and the issue doesn't occur.

I'm still curious why the HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH would be appended to the CWD (Current Working Directory).